# writing into /opt/folder

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm using gcsfuse with an app I am making to write files into `/opt/storage`
that folder is owned by a specific user called lets say "hero" which is in a group called "hero" too:

```
ls -al /opt:
drwxr-xr-x  1 hero hero    0 Apr 13 11:47 storage
```

when I do `sudo touch /opt/storage/file.txt`
works fine
but my app which is using this "hero" user cant write inside this folder without using `sudo`, is there a way to make this possible without having to add `sudo`?

do you think it would be a good idea to make a `ln` to another folder that is not in `/opt`? 
because right now this is the error I am getting in the terminal:

```
touch /opt/storage/file.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘/opt/storage/file.txt’: No such file or directory
```

but my app gets this error back:

```
system error: No such file or directory
```

I have just started working with Linux so I am a little confused, any help or advice would be awesome!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/opt is owned by root(admin user), you would need to change the owner to you, or just use the `sudo` command as below,

```
sudo touch /opt/storage/file.txt
```

### Update

If adding sudo is not fairly acceptable then change the ownership of folder, use chown

```
sudo chown -R username:username /opt/storage/
```

Comment: will it work if i change /opt/storage instead of the whole /opt folder? i read here that its really unsafe to do this

So if there is no other way arround this i will add sudo at the begining of the writting instruction

Comment: @AbdulHamid : Yes, changing the ownership is unsafe, adding `sudo` would definitely work.

Comment: @AbdulHamid : I have updated my answer, please check that too.

Answer (score 0):

As your output shows, the storage directory is owned by hero and hero is given full access. So this normally means you can do there anything you want, independently of what permissions/owner are set for /opt.
I am a bit confused about the error message from your terminal test.
You got "file not found". If you have a permission problem, you should get "permission denied" error.
I assume that the user you tested with, was hero.
Are you able to cd to /opt/storage and do ls -la?